# Modify default value of std::array using pybind11

Tags: python, c++, arrays, stl, pybind11

My goal is to modify array which are declared in `C++ struct` and assigned with default value.

I have read [this](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/stl.html#making-opaque-types), [this](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/stl.html#binding-stl-containers), but unfortunately I cannot relate it with my problem.

#### Sample Code

- C++

```cpp
class Math{
struct Data
{
  std::array<float, 5> id_ = {0}; // all value set to ZERO
  std::array<uint32_t, 5> length_ = {0}; // all value set to ZERO
  std::array<bool, 5> status_ = {0}; // all value set to ZERO
  float x_ = 7.5;
};
};
```

- Binded Code

```cpp
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <pybind11/complex.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(do_math, m)
{
    py::class_<Math::Data> Data (m, "Data");
    Data.def(py::init<>())
    .def_readwrite("id_", &Math::Data::id_)
    .def_readwrite("length_", &Math::Data::length_)
    .def_readwrite("status_", &Math::Data::status_)
    .def_readwrite("x_", &Math::Data::x_);
}
```

- Now, I would like to modify all `std::array` member value. I am only showing here `id_`.
- In `python file` I can access the `id_` member variable and it prints `[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]` as well as the `x_` which output is `7.5`

```py
import do_math
struct_obj = do_math.Data()
print(struct_obj.id_)
print(struct_obj.x_)
```

- Now would like to modify the value of `id_` but here I am unable to do it.

```py
struct_obj.id_[2] = 2.2 # cannot modify
struct_obj.x_ = 1.5 # it is modified
```

Still output of `struct_obj.id_` is `[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]` while `struct_obj.x_` is changed to `1.5`. How can I modify the `id_` array in python?

#### Approach has taken so far

By following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58723691/10634362) I have tried to implement but failed.

```cpp
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <pybind11/complex.h>
#include "pybind11/numpy.h"
#include <pybind11/pytypes.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(do_math, m)
{
    py::class_<Math::Data> Data (m, "Data", py::buffer_protocol());
    Data.def(py::init<>())
    .def_property("id_", [](Math::Data &p) -> py::array {
            auto dtype = py::dtype(py::format_descriptor<float>::format());
            auto base = py::array(dtype, {5}, {sizeof(float)});
            return py::array(
                dtype, {5}, {sizeof(float)}, p.id_, base);
        }, [](Math::Data& p) {});
}
```

- Error Message : `error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'py::array' return py::array(`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As several posts I have found that to wrap `std::array` there is no ready made solution in `pybind11` that's why I have followed [this answer](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/3155#issuecomment-889225194) to use `def_property` & `lambda expression` to assign/modify std::array from Python and return the value to python from C++.

- Binded code

```cpp
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <pybind11/complex.h>
#include "pybind11/numpy.h"
#include <pybind11/pytypes.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(do_math, m)
{
    py::class_<Math::Data> Data (m, "Data");
    Data.def(py::init<>())
    .def_property("id", [](Math::Data &self) {return self.id;},
                        [](Math::Data &self, std::array<float,5>buffer) 
                        {self.id = buffer;});
}
```

- Then usage from Python side

```py
import do_math
struct_obj = do_math.Data()
input_id = [1.1,2.2,3.3,7.8,0.5]
struct_obj.id = input_id # Now id can print the desired output
```

#### Although the approach has solved my issue but I am not satisfied. Reasons are following:

- Each time if I have to update `id` array, I have to change `input_id`. Time consuming and maintenance is hard. But it is the demand of the lambda expression which I have used
- Implementation of the wrapper in the binded code seems error-prone to me as I have to each time declare the array (for `buffer`) which has already declared in `cpp header/source file`. If I can get a way to write the wrapper in such way which can automatically detect the array(here `id`) and return the updated/assigned/modified value could be best.

Looking for a better and cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

Is the type of `struct_obj.id_` a pythonic `list`? I assume this is the problem. In such a case, a new pythonic list is created as a copy of the C++ array to offer a convenient Pythonic interface. However, this list is not connected anymore to the underlying C++ object because a `list` can not be a reference to a `std::array`.

The solution is either to assign `id_` directly instead of `id_[2]`:

```
l = struct_obj.id
l[2] = 2.2 # cannot modify
struct_obj.id = l
```

or to export `id_` [as an opaque object](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/stl.html#making-opaque-types) with `PYBIND11_MAKE_OPAQUE`.

Comment: I have tried to use `opaque object` but failed. Can you kindly show me an approach on the basis of my example?